# Justified navbar and display inline-block with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have created a justified navbar in Bootstrap 3. My problem is that when I add a display:inline-block to vertically align my items, the active and clickable area doesn't fill the width and height beetween the borders anymore (please bear with me, my english is rusty).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-justified">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Menu produits</span>
            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li><a href="#">Aliquam bibendum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aliquam</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Praesent eros ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quisque</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Suspendisse id dapibus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nullam consectetur dictum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aliquam bibendum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-justified {
text-align: center;
}

.nav-justified > li > a {
color: #2f2f2f;
font-size: 12px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.nav-justified > li {
    border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
}

.nav-justified > li:last-child {
border-right: 0;
}
```

Here is a Bootply link to see the code in action : http://www.bootply.com/Zkl1LHJr1v

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: Sorry for that, and thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 100%;` to `.nav-justified > li > a`. Then it should cover the whole length between the borders.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but there is still the height problem... I forgot to mention it in my original post. Салман gave me a hack, but I hope to find something.

Answer (score 0):

Since `li` is `display: table-cell`, its height increases due to two-lined `a`. However, small `a`s don't get the same height, so I think you could add `:hover` to the li as a hack to achieve the same effect.

```
li:hover {
    background: #EEE;
}
```

Till you find any better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the hack. I still hope I find a better solution to make the full height clickable.